# how to get 'device struct' from 'dev_t' in linux kernel programming?

Tags: linux, usb, kernel

I am quite new to kernel programming and I am following the tutorial given at : 
[USB boot authentication](http://ww2.cs.fsu.edu/~roy/KDD/Final_Paper.pdf)

I want to get a 'device struct' of a USB drive. I have 'dev_t' instance of the USB device. Further, I want to check whether the device struct is a USB device or not. I am not able to figure out how to start...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As hiteshradia said `dev_t` is a device number (a major number and minor number).  You can however use this along with the knowledge that it is for a block device to get access to the `struct device` associated with it.  To do so, use `struct block_device *bdget(dev_t)` from `linux/fs.h`.  From this you can use `block_device->bd_part` to get a `struct hd_struct *` for the device and finally use `struct device *part_to_dev(struct hd_struct *)` defined as a macro in `linux/genhd.h`.

Answer (score 1):

`dev_t` is only a device number which represents a `/dev/sdb1` partition as seen from your link. It is not possible to get the underlying usb drive details  using it.

In the link you provided there is section

```
if(udev->serial != NULL)
{
    if((strcmp(udev->serial, "3513001D97827E69")) == 0) /* Hard coded usb device serial here*/
    {
        key_dev_found = 1;
    }
}
```

where you can get usb device details and `struct usb_device *udev`